# Activate driver from C/C++ program Debian

Tags: c++, debian, driver, gpio

Trying to activate a GPIO driver from within a C/C++ program for BeagleBone Black-Debian.  Instead of activating the driver I get this error message "sh: 1: cannot create /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots: Directory nonexistent"  If I type "echo cape-bone-iio > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots" directly in the SSH terminal it works fine.  Any insights are appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
  {
  printf( "Activate Analog GPIO driver\n" );
  system( "echo cape-bone-iio > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots" );
  printf( "done\n" );
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Interestingly when I try to edit the file directly with nano or vim it won't let me save it but works fine with the echo command from the ssh shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, still not sure why echo didn't work.

```
FILE *ain;
ain = fopen("/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots", "w");
fseek(ain,0,SEEK_SET);
fprintf(ain,"cape-bone-iio");
fflush(ain);

fclose(ain);
return 0;
```